# How to achieve programming experience with PS3 or Xbox360?

Tags: xbox360, playstation3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get PS3/Xbox 360 experience without having access to Dev kits?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/how-to-get-ps3-xbox-360-experience-without-having-access-to-dev-kits)

Is there a way to achieve programming experience with PS3 or Xbox360 systems without the development kit that only are selling to great videogame companies ?

There are a lot of game companies that request experience with these systems and I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Alternatively, you could look into the homebrew communities around these consoles. I know Wii has a fairly well-developed homebrew community, I think PS3 has one as well...